# Bixby prompt for missing required input

Tags: bixby

I have an action with a required input for name:

```
action (ApiCall) {
  type (Search)
  collect {
    input (name) {
      type (viv.core.Name)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (ApiCallResponse) 
}
```

I also have an Elicitation dialog to prompt for the missing name:

```
dialog (Elicitation) {
  match: viv.core.Name
  template("What's your name?")
}
```

The prompt is correctly emitted when the name is not supplied. At this point, I want Bixby to accept the name and continue into the ApiCall action. I think I need a training for the name but I am not sure what to enter - all I get is errors for my various attempts. I looked at https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training in the section "Add Training Examples for Prompts".

I added a single name with a node of "viv.core.Name" same as all the other training entries for the name. I am not sure what to put for GOAL and the At Prompt For fields. All my other training uses ApiCall as the GOAL.

[image]

The errors in the image are

- ERROR training error: goal capsule mismatch, expected 1.1.0-webguild.namegame but got 0.0.0-viv.core
- ERROR training error: specialization capsule mismatch, expected 1.1.0-webguild.namegame but got 0.0.0-viv.core

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is a bit hard to read, but what it's saying is: You can't train to a goal that is *outside* of your capsule. `viv.core.Name` is not in `1.1.0-webguild.namegame` so it's going to fail.

Make a new model called `Name` like this,

```
name (Name) {
  description (A name that's inside my capsule.)
}
```

and you should be able to train on it.